# Is Possible to call multiple Php file in singel button click

Tags: php

In php, i want call multiple php files in single button click action

just like that

```html
<form action="php1.php , php2.php">   
  <form>
```

Is it possible ?? How can i call multiple files

Comment: No not really. But instead what you can do is use jquery for the second one. its the jQuery `.submit()` which might help you

Comment: you can make 2 different ajax calls to your action pages

Comment: look here: http://www.plus2net.com/html_tutorial/submit-two.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In action attribute can be only one file, but you can use for example include.

```
<form action="php1.php">...</form>
```

And php1.php file:

```
<?php
include 'php2.php';
// process form data
```

Answer (score 0):

Write whatever would be in php2.php as a function in php1.php and call it when you need.